# The only way to turn off/on wifi is to put laptop into sleep mode

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, wifi, hardware, sleep

After start GNOME prints `Hardware disabled`. I've tried to use keyboard shortcut and it doesn't work. Only way to disable/enable hardware wifi is to put laptop into sleep mode and restore.

Answer (score 3):

Also can check RF kill switches, try "rfkill list all", and if thats interesting persue further.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following should work: `ip link set wlan0 up`. Of course I'm not sure your wifi interface is `wlan0`, but you can check it by running: `iw dev`, and if it's like `wlan1`, just replace `wlan0` with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t have a problem to enable my wifi. My problem is that when i turn to sleep mode and resume it says that wifi is hardware disabled and the only way to enble it is to turn it to sleep mode again and resume it. It seems like the the fn+f1(sleep) and the fn+f2(sleep) are the same.

Comment: You shouldn't post this as an answer. If you think that some answer needs clarification, just comment to that answer. Also, now you say that your laptop's wifi turns off when you resume from sleep, and your question says almost opposite.